# Closing menu after clicking on it

Tags: wordpress

I built a website (friedl-bau.at), but I want the menu on the mobile version to dissappear after clicking on a category. So for example if I click on "Sehenswert", I want the menu to be closed. I am using the inspiro theme. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Copy & Paste this code into your theme functions.php file :

```
add_action("wp_head", "prefix_hide_mobile_menu_onclick");

function prefix_hide_mobile_menu_onclick() {
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#menu-menue .menu-item').click(function() {
               $('body').removeClass('side-nav-open');
            });             
        });
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: where do I have to put this code? into the costum css?

Comment: no it is a js (jquery) code ,  put it into a JS file and load it through wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: This answer could be improved with more details.